# Send a second confirmation email 24 hours after sign up with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise in my rails app and users can sign up then immediately sign in without having to confirm their email address for 24 hours. I did this with the `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for` option in the devise initializer.
I was wondering what would be the best way to send a second confirmation email, 24 hours after they sign up if they haven't confirmed their email address and that would say something like:

> "your account has been disabled because you haven't confirmed your
>   email address in the last 24 hours. Please click here to reactivate
>   your account"

I'm using sidekiq.
Any answer or suggestion will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a cron job to send the email after 24 hours.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: But I'm not just tying to send a second confirmation email, (I know how to do that) it would be a different email with a different message that still has the confirmation token in it.

Comment: Why did someone down vote my question ? Why don't you rather tell me what's wrong with my question

Comment: thats how ppl are sometimes. 
Sometimes they like to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sidekiq lets you [schedule jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs). At registration time, enqueue a job for 24 hours later that checks whether the user has been confirmed and if not, delivers the email.

First, you'll need the job, which simply accepts a user ID and send them mail:

```
class RegistrationReminder
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    return if user.confirmed_at # They already confirmed their email
    # Send them mail
  end
end
```

Then, [customize your Devise controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) with a [`sign_up`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2111) method that enqueues the job.

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def sign_up(resource_name, user)
    RegistrationReminder.perform_in(24.hours, user.id)
    super # Finish signing the user in
  end
end
```

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like how you keep it simple. However I'm also wondering how I can send a different message that still has the verification link. Do I have to make a specific mailer page ? How would that work with devise ? Am I trying to add too much unnecessary complexity ?

Comment: Devise adds a set of [url_helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb) you can use, but you'll need to write a mailer that uses it or resend one of Devise's built-in emails. The URL you want (if your resource is `User`) is `user_confirmation_path`.